# How can I fix this Vue script so that I don't need to click the dark mode button twice to take effect

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, laravel-10

I created a script to work on the dark mode button.

There is a problem, I have to click twice before the theme changes to dark.

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            "color-theme": "dark",
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        const themeToggleDarkIcon = document.getElementById('theme-toggle-dark-icon');
        const themeToggleLightIcon = document.getElementById('theme-toggle-light-icon');
        const savedTheme = localStorage.getItem("color-theme");
        if (savedTheme) {
            this.theme = savedTheme;
            document.documentElement.setAttribute("class", savedTheme);
        }

        if (localStorage.getItem('color-theme') === 'dark' || (!('color-theme' in localStorage) && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches)) {
            themeToggleLightIcon.classList.remove('hidden');
        } else {
            themeToggleDarkIcon.classList.remove('hidden');
        }
    },
    methods: {
        toggleTheme() {
            const themeToggleBtn = document.getElementById('theme-toggle');
            const themeToggleDarkIcon = document.getElementById('theme-toggle-dark-icon');
            const themeToggleLightIcon = document.getElementById('theme-toggle-light-icon');
            let event = new Event('dark-mode');

            themeToggleBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
                    // toggle icons
                themeToggleDarkIcon.classList.toggle('hidden');
                themeToggleLightIcon.classList.toggle('hidden');
                // if set via local storage previously
                if (localStorage.getItem('color-theme')) {
                    if (localStorage.getItem('color-theme') === 'light') {
                        document.documentElement.classList.add('dark');
                        localStorage.setItem('color-theme', 'dark');
                    } else {
                        document.documentElement.classList.remove('dark');
                        localStorage.setItem('color-theme', 'light');
                    }
                    // if NOT set via local storage previously
                } else {
                    if (document.documentElement.classList.contains('dark')) {
                        document.documentElement.classList.remove('dark');
                        localStorage.setItem('color-theme', 'light');
                    } else {
                        document.documentElement.classList.add('dark');
                        localStorage.setItem('color-theme', 'dark');
                    }
                }
                document.dispatchEvent(event);
            });
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

I was implementing on laravel splade and didn't find the right one. And I separated the script above into the Vue component.